# How do you remap the behaviour of the ALT key?

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys

By default the ALT key shows the current application menu.

I know that in general to remap shortcut keys you go to SystemSettings->Keyboard->shortcuts but I can't find one for the menu bar reveal.

If I hold down the super key, I get a list of current keyboard shortcuts. Under "HUD and Menu Bar" it says: 'Alt (hold)  Reveal the application menu'. This is the behaviour I wish to change.

Comment: How do you want its behavior to change? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: There is a feature in inkscape to allow selecting under the current object, which uses the alt key in combination with left mouse click. So actually I needed to remap the 'alt+left click' to allow the combination to pass to inkscape. CCSM let me modify that behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Use the CompizConfig Settings Manager (ccsm) and change the Unity plugin settings:

[image: CompizConfig Settings Manager]

To install: `sudo apt-get install ccsm`

Comment: @PhilipHoughton, if that answer works for you, consider accepting it, clicking on the **v** next to it, so others with a question similar to yours know this is a valid answer :)